# How to make my .csv text 'center aligned' using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have the following JS code that satisfactorily produces a `.csv` file and saves it in a user specified location:

**JS**

```
function generateCSV() {
  var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
  //Generates Valid CSV
  return csvContent
}

function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', text);
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
  pom.click();
}

$('#downloadCSV').click(function () {
    var csvContent = generateCSV();
    download("foobar.csv", encodeURI(csvContent));
});
```

My problem is that some of the text is left aligned while some is right aligned when I open it in MS Excel. How can I uniformly center-align all text programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by left aligned or right aligned? CSV is just coma separated strings.

Comment: @LeoDeng I mean that when I open it in MS excel, it is 'left aligned' and 'right-aligned' at random. I have added an edit for the same

Comment: If you want proper aligment you should create an execel document not csv file.

Comment: @Core_Dumped Alignment in Excel would depend on guessed type of the value. For example string is usually left aligned, number is usually right aligned. This also depends on your Excel settings for different data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alignment of columns in CSV documents opened in Excel is infered by the type of data. Text will be aligned differently than numbers and dates. If you want to force some alignment you can either change type of data in column (ie. you can add tabulation at the beginning of number to make it aligned like a text) or generate Excel file (xls or xlsx)

This is aligned to the right:

```
1;2;3
```

But this is aligned to the left:

```
    1;  2;  3
```

**Edit:**
Going back to your original question: There's no way to center data in CSV documents opened in Excel.